# when I am Trying to correct my spelling using grammarly that time remove sentence after incorrect spelling

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I have develop website using angular and my text box have a mask for validation.

when I am Trying to correct my spelling using grammarly that time remove sentence after the incorrect spelling

This issue generated on only Google Chrome. In Firefox working fine for me

Any limitations in angular?

Comment: You can add a screenshot with the spelling error that will help understand the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

So when you are loading your Angular application in Google Chrome browser, the Grammarly plugin in Chrome is showing you an error for some word and offering to auto-correct it?

If I have understood it correctly, then there is no problem in your Angular application as such. There is simply a spelling error. You can correct the spelling error in your Angular code and reload the page. Grammarly will stop showing error for spelling.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point. I have one textarea and mask applied for validation in angular 7. Now I writes the sentence and middle of the sentence there is wrong spelling. So when I auto correct the spelling using grammarly after rest of words are removed from text area. And this issue happens in only chrome browser. I checked in Firefox it's working perfectly fine.